# Latex citation undefined for inproceedings

Tags: biblatex

I got latex citation undefined for inproceedings only. Article works fine:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package


\addbibresource{cas-refs.bib} %Import the bibliography file


\clearpage
\printbibliography
```

Example of inproceedings:

```
@inproceedings{xyz,
  title={Hwllow world},
  author={bill, john},
  booktitle={2021 IEEE International},
  pages={1--4},
  year={2021},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

I tried to keep the example brief, but let me know if more details are required.

EDIT: I notice if I keep only "inproceedings" in the cas-refs.bib. It works fine.

EDIT 2: It seems I have made a mistake. It seems the problem with entery:

```
@article{Wang2022,
  title={Multiscale transunet +  + : dense hybrid U-Net with transformer for medical image segmentation},
  author={JOUR, Wang, Bo , Wang, ·Fan, Dong, Pengwei, Li, ·Chongyi},
  journal={https://doi.org/10.1007/s11760-021-02115-w},
  year={2022}
}
```

if I remove some of the authors, it works fine. It seems it was only able to handle up to three authors at max. I don't know why:

```
@article{Wang2022,
  title={Multiscale transunet +  + : dense hybrid U-Net with transformer for medical image segmentation},
  author={JOUR},
  journal={https://doi.org/10.1007/s11760-021-02115-w},
  year={2022}
}
```

Comment: The `.bib` entry you've given works fine with a minimal `biblatex` document. Does it not work for you? Are you saying that *all* `inproceedings` entries don't work, or just one specific one. Are you sure you've got the citation key correct? Keys are case-sensitive, so maybe that could be a problem?

Comment: all the inproceedings that I checked are flagged undefined. keys are the same. @Alan Munn

Comment: Then you need to construct a minimal document that shows the problem, because if I expand your code a bit to make it compilable, and use the `.bib` entry you show, the document compiles properly.

Comment: You can also look at your compiler's and/or Biber's output or log to see if they identify any problems.

Comment: Further to @cfr's comment, I suspect that there's an ill-formed `.bib` item in your `.bib` file and the `inproceedings` entries all follow that item and simply aren't being processed.

Comment: Yes I suspect that is the case .. please see my last edit @Alan Munn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bibtex` file format uses `and` as the author separator not a comma. So your entry:

```
@article{Wang2022,
  title={Multiscale transunet +  + : dense hybrid U-Net with transformer for medical image segmentation},
  author={JOUR, Wang, Bo , Wang, ·Fan, Dong, Pengwei, Li, ·Chongyi},
  journal={https://doi.org/10.1007/s11760-021-02115-w},
  year={2022}
}
```

is ill-formed and needs to be rewritten as follows:

```
@article{Wang2022,
    author = {Wang, Bo and Wang, Fan and Dong, Pengwei and Li, Chongyi},
    journal = {Signal, Image and Video Processing},
    month = jan,
    number = {6},
    pages = {1607--614},
    title = {Multiscale transunet + +: dense hybrid U-Net with transformer for medical image segmentation},
    volume = {16},
    year = {2022}}
```

The item also had some spurious characters and incorrect information. I retrieved the entry using the DOI.

The reason it looked like your `inproceedings` entries weren't working was likely because they so happened to be after this entry in the `.bib` file, and the file wasn't being read completely because of the error.

Comment: i think his best option is to use some bibtex validator before actually using the database, such as Mendeley Desktop